# How to remove same words?

Tags: java, arrays, string, equals

How to remove same words from string array?
Here is code example i want to use, but it does not working

```
String[] wordList = outString.toString().split(", ");
for (int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < wordList.length; j++) {
        if ((wordList[i].equals(wordList[j]))&&(j!=i)) {
            wordList.remove(wordList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `it does not working` Well that's not helpful at all! What does it do? Remove all the words? Throw an exception? Not do anything? How can we read your mind to find out the actual problem?

Comment: Suggest you sort the array, then for each word search forward until you find a non-matching word.

Comment: Do you mean removing duplicates?

Comment: This code won't even run... an `Array` doesn't have a `remove` method.
Try again...

Comment: Make the array a set. It will do it for you automatically.

Comment: `Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(wordList))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rule of Sets is that there can only be unique items in them. Therefore, the following code should suffice:

`Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(someArray));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(outString.split(", ")));
System.out.println(uniqueWords);
```